# jGRASP appletviewer not working (Path error)

Tags: java, jgrasp, appletviewer

CompSci student here.
for some reason, my jGRASP won't run when it requires an appletviewer to do do, saying "command 'appletviewer' not found in PATH or current working directory."

I have tried a lot of fixes including manually changing the path and re downloading everything, but for some reason, nothing seems to work.

Is there something I'm missing, or is this a bug I can fix?

Answer (score 0):

Installing a JDK (I recommend the latest one) should fix it. I remember JGRASP doesn't install that for you automatically like Eclipse or Android Studio.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

related problem:

https://sites.google.com/a/eng.ucsd.edu/cse-8b-winter-2014/schedule-and-assignments/psa7/set-up-appletviewer